# Behavior of Rc when the inner value is mutated

Tags: rust

In the following code snippet, why does the `count-1` prints `3` and `count-2` prints `1`. When the inner value of a Rc is mutated, why is it dropping `b and c` as reference holders? What is the behavior of Rc in such a case?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(u32, Rc<List>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let mut a = Rc::new(Cons(5, Rc::new(Cons(10, Rc::new(Cons(15, Rc::new(Nil)))))));
    let b = Cons(25, Rc::clone(&a));
    let c = Cons(30, Rc::clone(&a));

    println!("count-1 {}", Rc::strong_count(&a));

    let d = &mut a;
    *d = Rc::new(Cons(1, Rc::new(Nil)));

    println!("count-2 {}", Rc::strong_count(&a));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the inner value of a Rc is mutated, why is it dropping b and c as reference holders?

There's no mutating of inner values here, what you're doing is essentially the same as

```
a = Rc::new(Cons(1, Rc::new(Nil)));
```

So you're setting `a` to a brand new `Rc`, with a refcount of 1. `b` and `c` remain as-is, and the node `a` used to be has a remaining refcount of 2. Which you can see by accessing it via `b` or `c` e.g.

```
let Cons(_, a2) = &b else {
    return;
};
println!("{}", Rc::strong_count(a2));
```